# Unable to match Kinect SDK 3D data to Candide face model

Tags: sdk, kinect, video-tracking

According to multiple sources (one of them http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx) the Kinect SDK face vertices are based on the Candide-3 model (http://www.icg.isy.liu.se/candide/).

However, get3DShape() returns 121 3d vertices, while the Candide-3 model has only 113 vertices.

I want to map a frontal face picture to the 3d face shape; in order to do that I need to know which vertex corresponds to which point of the face/texture. How do i find this out?